# Are people who get genetically screened for diseases before marriage committing kufr?

Tags: nikah, kufr

This website is reporting that before getting married, potential couples are getting tested for genetic disease: http://www.arabnews.com/saudi-arabia/news/844656

This is a program that the Ministry of Health in Saudi Arabia wants every one to participate in. This program is for those who are getting married to a cousin. So basically under the program, before getting married to a cousin, the parties involved in the marriage contract undergo genetic screening to see if the union might potentially result in progeny with higher chance of genetically induced diseases. There are two outcomes of this screening:

1. The parties do not proceed with the marriage.
2. If the parties do proceed with the marriage, the idea of the screening is that this program will help the couple plan for combating the disease.

Now my question: are the people involved in the program committing kufr or nullifying their iman because they're challenging Allah SWT?

My point being that a Muslim must expect the best from Allah. So the couple expects that even though there is a higher chance of genetic disease developing in their offspring, they hope that Allah will bless them with a healthy child. However, at the same time if he/she develops plans to be ready for any eventuality to combat the genetic disease, is he/she manifesting evil thoughts about Allah SWT and thereby committing kufr?

Comment: Offtopic: Funny article at arabnews saying "high risk"... That's actually false.

Comment: To Kilise: Care to provide a link to an article that proves your point.

Comment: I am not sure the one wrote that article made his/hers research good enough, because "high risk" is just wrong, "increased risk" might be more accurate though. But not high risk. You could read at wikipedia, or in this link: http://genetics.thetech.org/ask/ask65 "But many genetic advisers argue that the increase isn't big enough to discourage marriage between first cousins."

Comment: @Kilise I would rather read this one http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110863013000037

Comment: The risk is not only about the diseases this test concerns, but also more complex issues such as epilepsy, mental retardness, ... Which cannot be predicted with this test.

Comment: @user5751924 As I said earlier, this discussion is rather off topic. Anyway, there are more studies available. What I wanted to point out is that "high risk" is misleading. Most studies suggest its an "increased risk" or "slightly increased risk".

Comment: Tie the camel first, then hope for the best in Allah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's far-fetched to consider this kufr.  In fact, nothing I found implied it's even haram.

An [IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90593) discouraged healthy people taking a premarital HIV test (without saying it's haram).  However, an [AboutIslam fatwa](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/family/can-marry-cousins/) said it is *good practice to have a blood test before marriage* in the context of cousin marriage.  So there seems to be nothing fundamentally haram about premarital testing.

I didn't find much about genetic testing in general, but there is one fatwa:

> Genetic testing is allowed in Islam for medical purposes.
>   <sub>Askimam, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/83825)</sub>

And an [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/267083) fatwa says *there is nothing wrong with undergoing genetic testing to find out what the problem is* about a woman with a physical deformity.

A more controversial issue is genetic testing of fetuses to determine whether or not to have an abortion.  Such diseases include [Down Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_syndrome) and [Spina bifida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spina_bifida), and in this context:

> Moreover, there is no objection in Islamic law to conducting the necessary tests to check for such incurable diseases and congenital defects.
>   <sub>[Dar Al-Ifta](http://eng.dar-alifta.org/foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=6738)</sub>

Section m4.0 of *The Reliance of the Traveller* talks about unsuitability for marriage:

> ... or someone with a defect that permits annulling the marriage (def: m7) for someone without such defects ...
>   <sub>*Reliance of the Traveler*</sub>

Among the conditions in m7 are *...the wife finds that the husband is
impotent...*, and various genetic diseases cause impotence; see  [Genetic causes of male infertility](https://andrologyaustralia.org/your-health/male-infertility-genetic-causes/).  So there are Islamic motivations for screening before marriage.